# Logical OR between query context and filter context with Elasticsearch 2.x

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an index with the following mapping:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "full_text": {
          "type":  "string" 
        },
        "exact_value": {
          "type":  "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I index a simple document like the following:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1
{
  "full_text":   "This is the city where I live", 
  "exact_value": "MILAN"  
}
```

What I want, it is to create a query that can be logically expressed as:

```
full_text:CONTAINS('live') OR exact_value:CONTAINS('MILAN')
```

But I want to search `full_text` in the query context while `exact_value` in the filter context

I tried with the following query but it doesn't work (replacing MILAN with ROME is the prove)

```
POST _search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : {
            "term" : {
              "exact_value" : "MILAN"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "should" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "live",
          "fields" : [ "full_text" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would try this :

```
POST my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "or": [
          {
            "term": {
              "exact_value": "MILAN"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "full_text": "live"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, as you want to use filter, please note that you won't have scoring.
Meaning that searching for "live OR MILAN" will produce the exact same response as "live OR ROMA" and "live"

The document actually containing "live or MILAN" might not be in first position

Comment: Your proposal works but it doesn't satisfy my request. I want to use a filter to improve performance

Comment: Sorry, I missed the filter part, please take a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
POST my_index/_search
{
"filter": {
  "bool": {
     "should": [
        {
           "term": {
              "exact_value": "MILAN"
           }
        },
        {
           "query": {
              "query_string": {
                 "default_field": "full_text",
                 "query": "live"
              }
           }
         }
       ]
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that can be built using the Java API

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [ {
        "bool" : {
          "filter" : {
            "term" : {
              "exact_value" : "MILAN"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "live",
          "fields" : [ "full_text" ]
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```